# Does RSS Include Kernel Space Memory?

Tags: linux, memory, linux-kernel

I am writing a simple memory profiler by reading the VmRSS value of /proc/[pid]/status. My question is that does a process' RSS include kernel space memory? Thank you!

Comment: No, I don't think so. Per process kernel memory is quite small.

Comment: On http://www.linuxintro.org/wiki/Memory_management I am blogging how I advance understanding Linux memory management. This is because I have not found a comprehensive documentation. Here is how I created a map of my processes' memory: pmap $(ps -A | awk '{print $1}'|grep -v PID) | sort

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, if you read the code in [task_mmu.c](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/fs/proc/task_mmu.c) you'll see that it's strictly pages allocated to the process.  Kernel space memory usage doesn't really have a quantifiable value at process scope.  Any memory increase in the kernel after a process starts execution should be negligible though.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK RSS tells how much user space memory given process occupies.